# I really don't understand why it's in 【bin/debug/netcoreapp 3.1】 the env.EnvironmentName value is production

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

Why is the running environment production for the compiled data in debug mode? This value is not set in the environment variable of my computer.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EnvironmentName` doesn't control, or get controlled by, the build type, it just tells you what the name of the environment is that you are currently *running* in.

If you want to control the actual build type use the "Solution Configurations" menu from the toolbar, or by right clicking on the solution in the Solution Explorer and choosing "Properties"

[image]

The actual `EnvornmentName` property can come from multiple sources, including environment variables, and `launchSettings.json`. If it isn't configured, it will default to `Production`.

`launchSettings.json` with the Environment set to `Development`:

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false, 
    "anonymousAuthentication": true, 
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:31746",
      "sslPort": 44369
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "WebApplication1": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This can also be set from the GUI by right clicking on the project, choosing "Properties", navigating to the "Debug" tab, and setting the "Environment variables" options there.

[image]

Full documentation can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: thank you.  because the aspnetcore was not read when the program started  Value of environment variable, which is production by default.   Although the generated code is in the directory of /bin/debug/netcoreapp3.1, it does not read the value of the environment【ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT 】 variable, so it takes the default value, which has no relationship with the directory. There was a problem with my previous understanding